# Why is UIKeyboardWillShowNotification called every time another TextField is selected?

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, first-responder

I have a project that contains a `UIScrollView` and many `UITextField` inside it.

For the first time I select a `UITextField`, `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is called, which is fine. But whenever I select new `UITextField` (THE KEYBOARD IS STILL THERE), `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is called again !!!, which is weird.

I also set a symbolic breakpoint for `[UIResponder resignFirstResponder]` and I see that it is hit before and after `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is called !!!

The other thing is that `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` is only called when I hit the "Done" button on the keyboard

I'm sure to not call any `resignFirstResponder`, `becomeFirstResponder`, `endEditing` anywhere. (I mean not call wrongly)

What can cause this problem ?

Here is the stacktrace
[image]

Comment: Why do you see this as a problem?

Comment: @matt Just edited it, I mean the keyboard is still there, but why UIKeyboardWillShowNotification is called again ?

Comment: By default, it should not be called twice so there must be something else going on in your code to provoke this action. If you create a project with two text fields and implement a notification using the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification name, your selector will only be called once.

Comment: @Chris thanks, so what can cause this problem? Some Gesture Recognizers, .. ?

Comment: Are you doing anything odd with gesture recognizers? Are you doing anything odd with `becomeFirstResponder`?

Comment: Are you doing anything odd with the responder chain?

Comment: i.e., are you doing anything odd? :)

Comment: From the looks of your print, there is a gesture recognizer being used and there is a notification being posted. Have you tried disabling any functionality related to the scope of the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification?

Comment: I'm asking because my stack is quite different from yours. It almost looks as if your text field is not being made the first responder - so that's why it happens again later.

Comment: Mine looks quite different as well.

Comment: In UIKeyboardWillShowNotification handler, I just modify the contentInset of the ScrollView, as suggest in Text Programming Guide. And my ViewController is a child of IIViewDeckController (which  has PanGestureRecognizer), but I don't think its a problem

Comment: Who says this is an error? UIKeyboardWillShowNotification should be called every time a new textfield gets focus, no matter if the keyboard was already there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is I set `inputAccessoryView` for the `UITextField`, and this cause `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` being called again when new `UITextField` is selected

This article [Working With Keyboard on iOS](http://macoscope.com/blog/working-with-keyboard-on-ios/) explains this well

> Additional changes take place when we connect an external keyboard to
>   the iPad. In this particular case, the notification behavior depends
>   on the inputAccessoryView property of the control which was the reason
>   for displaying the keyboard.
>
> If inputAccessoryView is not present or its height is equal to 0
>   points, no keyboard notifications are sent. My guess is that this is
>   because in this case, no visual changes take place in application.
>   Otherwise, all notifications behave as expected – which means they are
>   being sent as in the majority of cases when the keyboard is displayed
>   or hidden in a normal (not undocked or split) state.

Whenever new `UITextField` is selected, the OS needs to compute the frame for the keyboard again, and the following notifications are posted

```
UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
```

The same applies for when the TextField loses its first responder status

Note that using the **same** View for `inputAccessoryView` will cause `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` only called **once**

Comment: Can you please help me understand what is the solution to avoid receiving notification twice, I mean what is to be done in code ?

Comment: Under iOS 9, I am reusing the same view for my new text view's `inputAccesoryView` and both `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` are fired each time the new text view becomes active. Under iOS 8, no notifications are generated under this scenario.

Answer (score 22):

To workaround the problem, I used the following code to cancel the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` callback if the keyboard's frame is not changing.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    let beginFrame = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue()
    let endFrame = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue()

    // Return early if the keyboard's frame isn't changing.
    guard CGRectEqualToRect(beginFrame, endFrame) == false else {
        return
    }

    ...
}
```

For Swift 3/4:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {

    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let beginFrameValue = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)!
    let beginFrame = beginFrameValue.cgRectValue
    let endFrameValue = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)!
    let endFrame = endFrameValue.cgRectValue

    if beginFrame.equalTo(endFrame) {
        return
    }

    // Do something with 'will show' event
    ...
}
```

Comment: Much more elegant! Thanks for this!

Comment: I believe `beginFrame.equalTo(endFrame)` is the syntax for swift 3

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This really helped me in my situation.

Answer (score 5):

In general I find that many things can cause spurious `UIKeyboardWillShow` and `UIKeyboardWillHide` notifications. My solution is to use a property to track whether the keyboard is already showing:

```
func keyboardShow(_ n:Notification) {
    if self.keyboardShowing {
        return
    }
    self.keyboardShowing = true
    // ... other stuff
}

func keyboardHide(_ n:Notification) {
    if !self.keyboardShowing {
        return
    }
    self.keyboardShowing = false
    // ... other stuff
}
```

Those guards block exactly the spurious notifications, and all is well after that. And the `keyboardShowing` property can be useful for other reasons, so that it is something worth tracking anyway.

Comment: Nice answer. Very simple. However if the app needs to update its UI based on changes in keyboard height, this will guard out that attempt. For example, assume that the keyboard is open in a password textfield, and the phone receives the OTP code in SMS, the quick-type bar will be shown on the keyboard to autofill, changing its height.

In that case, @paulvs' answer works really well.

Comment: @badhanganesh Yes, I no longer use that approach. I use a much more sophisticated approach, seen here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p522textFieldScrollView/ch23p805textFieldSliding/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to Add notification & remove it once your purpose is solve.

like this .

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
// register for keyboard notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}
```

Now write your code for movement of views & textField in `keyboardWillShow` & revert them back to position in `keyboardWillHide` methods.

Also remove the observers

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
// unregister for keyboard notifications while not visible.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                              object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                              object:nil];
}
```

You can also resign the responder when you press `return` key.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [_txtFieldEmail resignFirstResponder];
    [_txtFieldPassword resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

That should solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't solve the problem , when we leave the view we remove the notification and thats a standard practice nothing to do with the above mentioned problem , its something to do with accessory view.

Answer (score 1):

For those not using inputAccessoryView but are still having problems, it may be due to using sensitive (password) fields. See this Stack Overflow post and answer: [keyboardWillShow in IOS8 with UIKeyboardWillShowNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832335/keyboardwillshow-in-ios8-with-uikeyboardwillshownotification)

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this, after half a day of searching around and experimenting I think this is the shortest and most reliable code.  It is a mix of a number of answers most of which I forget where I found (parts of which are mentioned here).

My problem was a WKWebView which (when the user changed fields) would spawn a load of WillShow, WillHide, etc notifications.  Plus I had problem with the external keyboard which still has the onscreen touch bar thing.

This solution uses the same animation code to "Open" and "Close" the keyboard, it will also cope with external keyboard being attached and custom keyboard views.

First register for the UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame:)                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

Then you simply need to map the changes to your view in however you do it (change a hight or bottom constraint constant).

```
- (void)keyboardWillChangeFrame:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    CGRect keyboardEnd = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect convertedEnd = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEnd fromView:nil];

    // Convert the Keyboard Animation to an Option, note the << 16 in the option
    UIViewAnimationCurve keyAnimation = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];

    // Change the Height or Y Contraint to the new value.
    self.keyboardHeightConstraint.constant = self.view.bounds.size.height - convertedEnd.origin.y;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]
                          delay:0.0
                        options:keyAnimation << 16
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     } completion:nil];

}
```

The Animation to Option conversion seems to work (I can only find examples of it being used and not how/why), however, I am not convinced it will stay that way so it may be wise to use a "stock" option.  It seems that the Keyboard uses some none specified Animation.