# iOS - Keyboard Notifications not firing while switching UITextfields

Tags: ios, nsnotifications, xcode10, ios12, swift4.2

There is a strange behavior going on with **notifications**. My notifications were firing properly whenever I switch one `UITextfield` to another. But recently I noticed they are not being fired now while switching from one `UITextField` to another but firing properly when the keyboard is hidden. Has **Apple** changed this logic?

I need to scroll the field to visible and as the **observers** are not firing now while switching, the fields don't come to visible rect.

I have created an alternative by posting notification on the `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, but I would like old way back if it is possible.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried all available code for swift 4 and swift 4.2 with no avail. I tried using observers with UIResponder (swift 4.2) and with Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow. Same behavior is observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the real reason of my issue. Keyboard notifications will not be called while switching if the `UITextfield` do not have accessory view and in case of accessory view they will be called each time ([Why is UIKeyboardWillShowNotification called every time another TextField is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549911/why-is-uikeyboardwillshownotification-called-every-time-another-textfield-is-sel/22553691))

In my case I had accessory view on each field but while adding accessory view I was adding same view to all of the fields, that was the real problem. I needed to assign separate instance of UIView to different fields. As soon as I did that my problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and I handled it via creating an accessoryView with a new button that is a duplication of my actual button. So basically, consider you have a `UIButton` which is sticking at the bottom of the `UIViewController` and you have 2 `UITextField` which when switched interchangeably, cannot feel that the `UIButton` was ever moved elsewhere but remain stuck on the keyboard. This following piece of code explains how to cater this problem:

```
@IBOutlet weak var signInBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

var accessoryViewKeyboard:UIView?
var btnAccessory:UIButton?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    passwordTextField.delegate = self
    emailTextField.delegate = self

    accessoryViewKeyboard = UIView(frame: signInBtn.frame)

    //Inputting the "accessoryViewKeyboard" here as the "inputAccessoryView" is of 
    //utmost importance to help the "signInBtn" to show up on tap of different "UITextFields"
    emailTextField.inputAccessoryView = accessoryViewKeyboard
    passwordTextField.inputAccessoryView = accessoryViewKeyboard

    setupBtnWithKeyboard()
}

func setupBtnWithKeyboard() {
    btnAccessory = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: signInBtn.frame.origin.x, y: signInBtn.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: signInBtn.frame.size.height))
    accessoryViewKeyboard?.addSubview(btnAccessory!)
    btnAccessory?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btnAccessory?.frame = CGRect(x: (accessoryViewKeyboard?.frame.origin.x)!,
                                 y: (accessoryViewKeyboard?.frame.origin.y)!,
                                 width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                                 height: (accessoryViewKeyboard?.frame.size.height)!)

    btnAccessory?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 31/255, green: 33/255, blue: 108/255, alpha: 1)
    btnAccessory?.setTitle("Sign In", for: .normal)
    btnAccessory?.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 22)
    btnAccessory?.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    btnAccessory?.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    btnAccessory?.isEnabled = true
    btnAccessory?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SignIn.signInBtnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        btnAccessory!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:
            accessoryViewKeyboard!.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        btnAccessory!.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:
            accessoryViewKeyboard!.centerYAnchor),
        btnAccessory!.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:
            accessoryViewKeyboard!.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        btnAccessory!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: signInBtn.frame.size.height),
        ])
}
```

And you're done. This will keep the `UIButton` always present on the Keyboard. Important thing is no matter how many instances of `UITextField` you introduce, always input the `accessoryViewKeyboard` as its `inputAccessoryView`.